# Accessing child XML elements iteratively with Ruby and Nokogiri

Tags: ruby, nokogiri

I have an XML file similar to this:

```
<Companies type="Container">
<Company type="Category">
    <Name type="Property">Company 123</Name>
    <Location type="Property">New York</Location>
    <Employees type="Container">
        <Employee type="Reference">
            <Name type="Property">John Smith</Name>
            <Email type="Property">john@company.123</Email>
        </Employee>
        <Employee type="Reference">
            <Name type="Property">Jane Doe</Name>
            <Email type="Property">jane@company.123</Email>
        </Employee>
</Company>
<Company type="Category">
    <Name type="Property">Company ABC</Name>
    <Location type="Property">Minneapolis</Location>
    <Employees type="Container">
        <Employee type="Reference">
            <Name type="Property">John Doe</Name>
            <Email type="Property">doe@company.abc</Email>
        </Employee>
        <Employee type="Reference">
            <Name type="Property">Jane Smith</Name>
            <Email type="Property">smith@company.abc</Email>
        </Employee>
</Company>
```

I have to walk through this file and get all the information out so I can work with it. I can use Nokogiri to loop through and access each 'Company' and get the 'Name' and 'Location' properties just fine. What I can not figure out how to do, however, is to access the 'Employee' information for each 'Company'.

I'm sure I am missing something simple, but I've been digging around within pry and I can not seem to demystify this. Help would be *greatly* appreciated.

Comment: Please post your code for getting the Name and Location. Since there are so many ways to do things with Nokogiri, I can try to tailor my answer to the methods you've chosen to use.

Comment: Please also fix your xml. The Name type is missing close quotes, and `Employee` and `Companies` closing tags are missing. Nokogiri's default parse mode doesn't complain, but you'll be getting the wrong data back.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Note: I highly recommend passing the args `(raw_xml_string, nil, nil, Nokogiri::XML::ParseOptions::STRICT)` when developing, to catch malformed xml.

```
xdoc = Nokogiri.XML(raw_xml_string)

( xdoc/'/Companies/Company' ).each {|com|
  puts "company:"
  p [(com/'./Name').text, (com/'./Location').text]

  puts "employees:"
  # you need another loop to grab the employees.
  (com/'Employees/Employee').each {|emp|
    p [(emp/'./Name').text, (emp/'./Email').text]
  }
}
```

One thing to note when you're using the `/` or `%` methods is that they will select any descendant, not just the direct child. Which is why I used `'./Name'` instead of just `'Name'`.

Answer (score 2):

Your XML is malformed.

Nokogiri can help you find out where the problem is using the `errors()` method. Parsing the XML and checking `errors()`:

```
doc = Nokogiri::XML(xml)
puts doc.errors
```

outputs:

```
Unescaped '<' not allowed in attributes values
attributes construct error
Couldn't find end of Start Tag Name line 4
Opening and ending tag mismatch: Company line 3 and Name
Opening and ending tag mismatch: Employees line 6 and Company
Unescaped '<' not allowed in attributes values
attributes construct error
Couldn't find end of Start Tag Name line 17
Opening and ending tag mismatch: Company line 16 and Name
Opening and ending tag mismatch: Employees line 19 and Company
```

Nokogiri will try to fix up the XML but some things it can't do correctly. Fixing missing quotes is one of those things:

```
<Name type="Property>Company 123</Name>
<Name type="Property>Company ABC</Name>
```

are wrong. They should be:

```
<Name type="Property">Company 123</Name>
<Name type="Property">Company ABC</Name>
```

Also, the closing tags for `</Employees>` is missing in both cases but Nokogiri will fix those.